# Returned error: gas required exceeds allowance (91135865401031) or always failing transaction

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, private-blockchain, gas-limit, clients

I am trying to deploy smart contract on private network and do transactions via nodejs script. This is my genesis block:

```
{
    "config": {
        "chainId": 16,
        "homesteadBlock": 0,
        "eip155Block": 0,
        "eip158Block": 0
    },
    "alloc": {},
    "difficulty" : "200",
    "gasLimit" : "99999999999999"
}
```

I have used following command to start the network:

```
geth --datadir ./exp4 --networkid 16 --rpc --rpcapi "eth,net,web3,personal,miner" --nodiscover --allow-insecure-unlock --port 3000 console
```

I am deploying it using truffle. This is my smart contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.8;
contract Hello {
   string public message;
   function HelloWorld() public{
       message = "Hello, World : This is a Solidity Smart Contract on the Private Ethereum Blockchain ";
   }
}
```

Migration file:

```
var Hello = artifacts.require("./Hello.sol");
module.exports = function(deployer) {
   deployer.deploy(Hello);
};
```

Truffle config:

```
rpc: {
    host:"localhost",
    port:8545
},
networks: {
    development: {
        host: "127.0.0.1",     // Localhost (default: none)
        port: 8545,            // Standard Ethereum port (default: none)
        network_id: "16",      // Any network (default: none)
        from: "0xc3ec8cfb877b639094d2bc4bb99651dcb0c36aff",
        gas: 20000000
    }
}
```

Finally, I am running this script which gives the error as mentioned in title of gas limit exceeding

```
var Web3 = require('web3')
var web3_http = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://127.0.0.1:8545'));
const fs = require('fs');
const con = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./build/contracts/Hello.json', 'utf8'));
var abi = con.abi;
web3_http.eth.getBalance("0xc3ec8cfb877b639094d2bc4bb99651dcb0c36aff")
.then(console.log);
var cont = new web3_http.eth.Contract(abi, "0xdCf9a6832Fae44B081f62513D04c2E30fB9a6A00");
console.log(cont);

cont.methods.HelloWorld().estimateGas({from: "0xc3ec8cfb877b639094d2bc4bb99651dcb0c36aff"})
.then(function(gasAmount){
    console.log(gasAmount);
})
.catch(function(error){
    console.log(error);
});
```

`0xc3ec8cfb877b639094d2bc4bb99651dcb0c36aff` is the account address and `0xdCf9a6832Fae44B081f62513D04c2E30fB9a6A00` is the address at which my contract is deployed. It  shows correct ether value for my account and fetches the contract correctly but gives a gas limit exceeding error when estimating gas. I was initially trying to deploy a personal contract which was much more complex and it gave the same error. So, I tried deploying a simple contract but it still shows the same error. Link to my previous [question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/77006/getting-gas-required-exceeds-allowance-93846700840810-or-always-failing-trans):

It would be really helpful if anyone could tell what it is that I doing wrong.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100662/discussion-on-question-by-tanay-bhartia-returned-error-gas-required-exceeds-all).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to setup constantinople fork for private ethereum chain](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/67794/how-to-setup-constantinople-fork-for-private-ethereum-chain)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting "gas required exceeds allowance (93846700840810) or always failing transaction" on private network. How to access geth client via nodejs?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/77006/getting-gas-required-exceeds-allowance-93846700840810-or-always-failing-trans)